# Recover USB Bluetooth dongle PIN (Acer BT-600)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bluetooth

I found and old Acer BT-600 USB BlueTooth Dongle and wanted to use it to pair my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop with my Nexus 5.

On pairing I my Nexus asks about the BlueTooth Dongle PIN, but I have no idea about it...

Is there a way to recover it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried any pins yet? like "1234" ? I will see if I can find a list somewhere but I thought this was the default on a lot of bluetooth adapters.

Comment: Yes, I tried 0000 and 1234 to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible to use any sort of scripting to try each possible PIN in an exhaustive search? Or is there no way to answer the PIN request with a script?

Comment: Did you set it up as this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html) explains?

Comment: I also thought about it. But I have to enter the pin in my mobile and do not know a way how to automate that. I keep researching....